# Route Attribute Ignored

Tags: routes, servicestack

According to [multiple](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-API) documentation [sources](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing), routes can be defined as attributes on the DTO. I have the following DTOs (the last one is in a different file):

```
[Route("/hdos", "GET")]
public class GetHdos
{
    public bool IncludeAdminUsers { get; set; }
}

[Route("/hdos/{Id}", "GET")]
public class GetHdo
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

[Route("/hdos/{HdoId}/facilities", "GET")]
public class GetHdoFacilities
{
    public Guid HdoId { get; set; }
}
```

Housed by the following services (the last one is in a different file):

```
public object Get(GetHdos request)
{
    return _hdos.GetAll(request.IncludeAdminUsers);
}

public object Get(GetHdo request)
{
    return _hdos.GetById(request.Id)
}

public object Get(GetHdoFacilities request)
{
    return _hdos.GetFacilities(request.HdoId);
}
```

A call to any of

```
/hdos
/hdos/a82b955195e34bfda2fdde7da68f8992
/hdos/a82b955195e34bfda2fdde7da68f8992/facilities
```

Returns `Method not supported`. But if I call them as the class name, the routes are hit. Is there something I am missing? Do I need to activate these routes in the `AppHost` somehow?

Comment: In your AppHostBase constructor do you specify the assemblies to find your services? Also not sure what you mean by calling them by the class name?

Comment: I do add the serve assemblies, yes. Do I need to add the DTO assemblies? and I mean if I call the url `/gethdos` or `/getHdo` the first or second service is hit (respectively). This is the default routing convention, the DTO class name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like ServiceStack maps your route differently for the REST and HTTP types. I didn't mention in the question that I was calling `Json/syncreply/hdos` Because I thought the `Json/syncreply` was part of every call. I was wrong. If you do that, it will look for the DTO class name as the route.

To use the Route declared on the DTO as an attribute, you just call the route, leaving off the `json/syncreply`. The inverse is not directly stated in the documentation, but I was confused nonetheless.

Comment: Right, [pre-defined auto routes should not be confused with user-defined custom routes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing#pre-defined-routes).